# QualysGuard API - SYNTAX issue - parameter rsa_private_key

Tags: linux, bash, api

I need to know the RSA key format to be sent to Qualys for updating an authentication record via Qualys API.

Below technique gives me "parameter rsa_private_key has invalid value" error:

```
$ test2="$(<~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
$ curl -H "X-Requested-With: Curl" -u "cenga_vg:ZZZZ" -X "POST" -d "action=update&ids=YYYY&rsa_private_key=$test2" "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/auth/unix/" -D headers
```

## Error:

parameter rsa_private_key has invalid value: improper RSA private key format

========================================

Comment: Did you try URL encoding the data the way the curl docs say the input to `-d` needs to be encoded?

Comment: It worked with --data-urlencode

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -H "X-Requested-With: Curl" -u "cenga_vg:ZZZZ" -X "POST" --data-urlencode "action=update&ids=YYYY&rsa_private_key=$test2" "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/auth/unix/" -D headers
```